# Strange error using strstr

Tags: c, substring, strstr

I am currently implementing a SML Reader for Smart Meters on a `STM32F0`.
Everything works fine, but I have problems using `strstr` from `string.h`

Current Situation:

I have a char Array Data, which contains all Data coming in over USART. It contains Hexnumbers and a valid Textstring.

Somewhere in this String there is this Sequence:
`{0x01,0x01,0x62,0x1b,0x52,0x00,0x55}`.

I want to find the position of this substring in the Datastring using `strstr`.

It works just fine with this example string, that is always at the very beginning of the Datastring: `{0x1b,0x1b,0x1b,0x1b,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x76,0x05}`

But if I use the other substring it doesn't work.

Here is my Code:

```
const char needle[] = {0x01,0x01,0x62,0x1b,0x52,0x00,0x55};
    if((needle_ptr = strstr(Data,needle)) == NULL){
        //No Active Power String detected
        flags &= ~NewPowervalue;    //Reset NewPowervalue flag
    }else{

        Powervalue = (needle_ptr[14]<<24) + (needle_ptr[15]<<16) + (needle_ptr[16]<<8) + (needle_ptr[17])/10000;
        //Extract and calculate Powervalue
        flags |= NewPowervalue;     //Set NewPowervalue flag
        Poweroutlets(&Powervalue);
        GPIOC->ODR ^= BLED;
    }
```

Has anyone a clue what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Probably the occurrence of the 0x00 character is the problem, which strstr interprets as a string terminator.

Comment: in general, treating this data from the USART as string data seems foolish to me. A string is "Hey, how are you doing?" If you can't represent all your data in printable ASCII characters (or whatever character encoding you're using), you shouldn't be using string functions. If there is a string embedded in the data you are receiving, parse that out first if you want to use string functions on it. Use [`memcpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) and friends when dealing with binary data, or write your own parsing functions.

Comment: Note that you are (un)lucky that the 0x1b…0x05 'string' works because you have not terminated that string with a null byte (0x00) and `strstr()` goes reading out of bounds of the array.  If you're using `strstr()` or the string-handling functions, you have to make sure you're dealing with null-terminated strings.  As noted by (at least) one of the answers, the `memmem()` function is the analogue of `strstr()` for bounded-length memory work.  It is not, however, a POSIX function (let alone standard C), but it may be more widely available than that suggests (Linux, macOS, AIX, … have it).

Comment: Interestingly, the macOS documentation for `memmem()` notes: _     This function was broken in Linux libc up to and including version 5.0.9 and in GNU libc prior to version 2.1._   Treat that with whatever size pinch of salt you deem appropriate.  It probably won't affect you anyway.

Comment: Just a niggling thought... this textstring-that-isnt that arrives from the USART - how do you know where the start/end is if it can contain any char value, including NUL?

Comment: The SML Message that comes over USART includes a Start and Stop Sequence. Also the Messages are not transferred continuously, but in pulses every 1-4 seconds

Answer (score 3):

Of course it does not work, because 0x00 is the asciiz terminator, and `strstr()` compares asciiz-terminated strings, so it stops comparing at 0x00.

The other example string you showed works because it does not contain any 0x00s.

So, what it boils down to is that you do not want to compare strings, (as strings are defined in C,) but areas of memory.

So, you will either have to use the `memmem()` function, if your runtime library has it, or write your own, it should not be difficult.  (It should not be difficult to even find the source code of some implementation of `memmem()`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. With memmem it works fine! I didn't put a '\0' at the end of the string, because without it it also works. So i didn't just it anymore